# Curved spacetime generalization of Bethe-Salpeter equation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, propagator, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I am interested in the problem of bound states in QFT in curved spacetime. I was wondering if the generalization of the [Bethe-Salpeter equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethe%E2%80%93Salpeter_equation) is as simple as replacing the Green’s functions in the equation with their curved spacetime counterparts.

Comment: I am not aware of the Bethe-Salpeter equation, but I think in general, replacing something in flat space with a curved spacetime counterpart is the tricky bit. Maybe expand on the equation a bit?